# How to read empty file in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm using the readdir method to read a list of files from directories to an array.  May I know how to read the zerro size file as the readdir will only read non-zerro file only.  I would like to read the empty file as well (capture the file name as treat as exist even it is empty).  May I know how to do so?  Below is how I read the file from directories:-

```
opendir (FH, $dirs) || die $! ;
my @lines = readdir (FH) ; 
closedir (FH) ;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code works fine for me and includes the names of empty files. Please post more information about what is not working for you.

Comment: "the readdir will only read non-zerro file only" is not true. `readdir` will read all file names, regardless of size. You can try it out with `perl -lwe 'opendir F,"." or die $!; while (readdir F) { print unless -s }'`  Where `unless -s` means "if size != 0".

Comment: Re "readdir will only read non-zerro file only", `readdir` doesn't read files, and it doesn't filter the files it returns based on their length (or any other factor).

Comment: HI Greg Hewgill, TLP and all who spent time on helping me to solve this question.  I did a small script on testing the readdir and it did capture the zerro content files.  It was able to read the  empty file and indeed it was my other part of code error :(.  Sorry for that I should have more careful next time.  Great help from all you guys!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use a bare-word directory handle.  Second, [`-z` tells you when a file is empty](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).  Something like this should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dirs="/whatever/dir/you/want";

opendir(my $dh,$dirs) or die $!;

#only grabbing actual files that we can read.
my @files=grep{(-f $_) and (-r $_)} map{"$dirs/$_"} readdir($dh); 

closedir($dh);

foreach my $file(@files)
{
  if(-z $file)
  {
    print "File $file is empty.\n";
  }
  else
  {
    print "File $file is not empty.\n";
  }
}
```

In fact, as TLP pointed out in the comments, you can use `-s` to get the size (in bytes) of the file.

Comment: `for my $file (grep -f, readdir $dh)` saves you some typing. But I do not think he is asking for zero size files, he thinks that readdir ignores zero size files.

Comment: True, that is more compact.  Truth be told, upon rereading the question, I'm not sure whether or not the OP wants to keep zero-size files or not....

Comment: `readdir` doesn't return file paths, just file names. Fixed. (@TLP's code has the same problem.)